# How to import multiple xlsx sheets in R

Tags: r, excel, database, import

I am learning R studio right now and I was just wondering how do I import an xlsx file with multiple sheets (8 sheets).

So far.. I have:

```
library(readxl)
(filename) <- read_excel("(file location).xlsx")
view(filename)
```

It prints out only the first sheet of the excel file, but I would appreciate it if it printed out all of them.

Also, is it better to use CSV files or xlsx?

thanks, guys.

Comment: IMHO: csv usually works better and faster, but if your data is already stored (and formatted!) in excel,please leave it there.

Comment: yes my data is stored/formatted in excel already. I noticed csv only saves one particular sheet. can save more than one at once?

Comment: yes, use/write a simple vba macro

Comment: @Wimpel ty!! just figured it out yesterday. last question, my data is formatted but then it reads weirdly in R, like the data has lots of spaces in it. is there anyway to fix this? lmk if this is unclear, im not the best at explaining

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do

```
lst <- lapply(1:8, function(i) read_excel("file_name.xlsx", sheet = i))
```

This will store all 8 sheets in a `list` of `data.frame`s.

Comment: can you explain to me what function(i) means?

Comment: @DavidLuong `function(i)` just defines a `function` of `i`. If you're asking about `function`s in R, take a look at ``?`function` ``.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for all sheets in the workbook

```
lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)
```

read `?excel_sheets`