# How to merge a set of lists into a single data frame

Tags: r, list, merge, lapply, rbind

I am new to R and coding in general, so please bear with me.

I have a spreadsheet that has 7 sheets, 6 of these sheets are formatted in the same way and I am skipping the one that is not formatted the same way.

The code I have is thus:

```
lst <- lapply(2:7,
              function(i) read_excel("CONFIDENTIAL Ratio 062018.xlsx", sheet = i)
             )
```

This code was taken from this post: [How to import multiple xlsx sheets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838810/how-to-import-multiple-xlsx-sheets-in-r)

So far so good, the formula works and I have a large list with 6 sub lists that appears to represent all of my data.

It is at this point that I get stuck, being so new I do not understand lists yet, and really need the lists to be merged into one single data frame that looks and feels like the source data (so columns and rows).

I cannot work out how to get from a list to a single data frame, I've tried using R Bind and other suggestions from here, but all seem to either fail or only partially work and I end up with a data frame that looks like a list etc.

Comment: What's your data like? we need at least a reproducible example.. Are alle the sheets the same, they need to have the same number of columns and the same column names, otherwise you can't bind them.

Comment: If they are the same you can use `dplyr` and the function `bind_rows`. Like this: `require(dplyr); my_dataframe <- bind_rows(my_list)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying to me. The data has 71 columns wide and between 500-800 rows. Every sheet is identical in format, just each sheet has a different name and a different number of rows (because each sheet has different customers).

Comment: then my suggestion above should work. I can't test it because there's no reproducible example of the data.

Comment: Seems to work a treat, you're a genius. I knew it would have to be something simple, but I just couldn't get it! Thank you @RLave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each sheets has the same number of columns (`ncol`) and same names (`colnames`) then this will work. It needs the `dplyr` pacakge.

```
require(dplyr)
my_dataframe <- bind_rows(my_list)
```